# StaticResource for StringFormat in win phone not working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have declared a resource in Application.Resources like

```
 <sys:String x:Key="DecimalFormat">\{0:F2\}</sys:String>
```

Now on textbox I giving this static resource as StringFormat but its not working. I also tried  binding of stringFormat application breaks. Is there any I want to make stringformat dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it without the slash when defining as a resource

```xml
<sys:String x:Key="DecimalFormat">{0:F2}</sys:String>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDecimal, StringFormat={StaticResource DecimalFormat}}"  />
```